# sort array by its value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array and when I console.log it it give me this:

```
[paris: 348589.40826358093, londres: 490078.8871883664, nantes: 6363.461319105993]
```

I want to sort the array by the value (the number), be I can't figure how to do it.
i want a result order by the value like this:
    [nantes: 6363.461319105993, paris: 348589.40826358093, londres: 490078.8871883664] 
I have try with something like this but it's not working.

```
function compare(x, y) {
  return x - y;
}
tab.sort(compare);
```

Comment: your array is wrong declared.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

Comment: That's not an array. It's not even valid JavaScript.

Comment: Have read [here](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/) to find out more about associative arrays and what Javascript syntax should be used with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array declaration is wrong. If you want to use name for items you should use js objects like below code.

```
var tab = {paris: 56765, londres: 3456546, 'new york': 25455654}
```

or

```
var tab = [{paris: 56765}, {londres: 3456546}, {'new york': 25455654}]
```

But if you want to have sort by that compare function, do something like this:

```
var tab = [{name: paris, value: 56765}, {name: londres, value: 3456546}, {name: 'new york', value: 25455654}]
```

and change compare method to this:

```
function compare(x, y) {
  return x.value - y.value;
}
```

If you want to have more condition in your js object can use [this js library](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score -1):

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> Objects can be sorted given the value of one of their properties.
>
> ```
>     var items = [
>   { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
>   { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
>   { name: 'And', value: 45 },
>   { name: 'The', value: -12 },
>   { name: 'Magnetic' },
>   { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
> ];
> items.sort(function (a, b) {
>   if (a.name > b.name) {
>     return 1;
>   }
>   if (a.name < b.name) {
>     return -1;
>   }
>   // a must be equal to b
>   return 0;
> });
> ```

That should give you the idea

Comment: that's not what i whant. i want to sort my array by the value which is the numbers. By what I understand this can only sor by name in your exemple